# Background larger than its container

Tags: html, css, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to achieve this layout but I'm having problems with setting a background, which should be 50% of the screen size. I thought of setting up an image as background, but there are different colors that should be different on each page.

[image: screen]

Is it possible to achieve it using only `background-color`?

This is how I set the HTML, TS & CSS so far:

```
<div [class]="getBackground(title)">
  <div class="background-header">
    <img [src]="'assets/assess/Custom.png'" alt="">
    {{title}}
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let theme of pillar.data; let i = index">
        <button rh-btn-theme  full-btn [ngClass]="{'ripple': true}" [issue]="theme" (click)="presentModal($event, theme);"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
getBackground(pillar) {
  switch (pillar) {
    case "People":
      return "background-people";

    case "Land":
      return "background-land";   

    case "Crop":
      return "background-crop";     

    case "Business":
      return "background-business";

    default:
      return "background-custom";
  }
}
```

CSS

```
  .background-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    img {
      display: inherit;
      background-color: #000;
    }
  }

  .background-people {
    background-color: #335F6E;
  }
  .background-land {
    background-color: #006533;
  }
  .background-crop {
    background-color: #7F4020;
  }
  .background-business {
    background-color: #F8DC0B;
  }
  .background-custom {
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by `background gradient`:

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 2px #123;
  background: linear-gradient( red, red 50%, white 50%, white);
}
```

```html
<div class='content'></div>
```

Dont forget genarte cross-browser css. See about `background gradient` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)